# CSS spacing is off, not sure what's causing

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm working on a form and need to include a note above the reCAPTCHA field. I've got everything in place, but the spacing between the *To submit your message, please type the words shown below: note and reCAPTCHA is way off, I need to figure out how to bring the two elements closer together vertically.

I'm using a paragraph tag in the form for the note, I'm not sure if that's bad form??

**[Website Link](http://tinyurl.com/cm3zzuw)**

**CSS:**

```
/*Prayer Request Form*/

#prayer-form {  
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 960px;
    height: 520px;
    padding: 40px 30px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;


}


form, fieldset, input, textarea {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: none;
}


label {
    float: left; clear: left; margin: 11px 20px 0 0; width: 65px;
    text-align: left; font-size: 14px; color: #000000; 

}


input {
    width: 370px; height: 20px; padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; margin: 0 0 23px 0; 
    background: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid #808080;  
    font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;
}



textarea {
    width: 650px; height: 120px; padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; 
    background: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    overflow: auto; 
    font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;
}


input[type=submit] {
    width: 95px; height: 30px; float: left; clear: left; padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px; margin: 20px 0 0 85px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #0000CD;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #00BFFF 0%, #0000CD 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#00BFFF), color-stop(100%,#0000FF)); /* webkit */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#00BFFF', endColorstr='#0000CD');
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=reset] {
    width: 95px; height: 30px; float: left; padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px; margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #858585;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EDEDED 0%, #999999 100%); /* firefox */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#EDEDED), color-stop(100%,#999999)); /* webkit */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#EDEDED', endColorstr='#999999');
    cursor: pointer;
}


p captcha{
float: left; padding: 2px 0 0 85px;
font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;

}

#captcha {
    float: left; margin: 11px 0 20px 0; width: 445px; height: 110px; padding: 2px 5px 2px 85px;


}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!--/ Show Prayer Request Form-->

<div id="prayer-form">


<form name="prayer-form" action="send-mail.php" method="POST">

<label for="field_name">Name:</label> <input type="text" id="field_name" name="sender_name" placeholder="First Name, Last Name"> 
<br>
<label for="field_email">Email:</label> <input type="text" id="field_email" name="sender_email" placeholder="example@domain.com">
<br>
<label for="field_phone">Phone:</label> <input type="text" id="field_phone" name="sender_phone" placeholder="(444) 444-4444">
<br>
<label for="field_message">Prayer Request:</label>

<textarea id="field_message" name="sender_message" placeholder="How can we pray for you?"></textarea>

<p id="captcha"><b>*To submit your message, please type the words shown below:</b></p>

<div id="captcha">
    <?php
          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "*****************AzBk";
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
</div>


<input type="submit" name="send_message" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" value="Reset">

</form>

</div>
```

***Your help is much appreciated.***

Comment: you have assigned the same styles to your <p> tag as your captcha <div> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust the following rule in your style sheet:

```
#captcha {
    float: left; 
    margin: 11px 0 20px 0; 
    width: 445px; 
    height: 110px; 
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 85px;
}
```

You don't need to specify the height, just use `height: auto` or omit it all together.

You can also omit the `padding`, using `margin` alone will give you enough control.
Finally, you may not need to float the paragraph.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it. The left spacing from the *note has now disappeared, any idea what could be causing that?

Comment: On the paragraph of interest, adjust the margin by using the rule: `margin-left: 85px;` on `p#captcha-desc`.  This will line up the left edge of the paragraph with the textarea above it.  85px comes from 65px width of the label and its 20px right margin.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's the `height` setting in your captcha CSS:

```
#captcha {
    float: left;
    margin: 11px 0 20px 0;
    width: 445px;
    height: 110px;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 85px;
}
```

When I disable the height setting of 110px, the spacing is more reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have set your  with the same id as the actual captcha form you must change the id on the

tag, plus it is not good to have 2 ID's.

change to this -

```
<p id="captcha-notice"><b>*To submit your message, please type the words shown below:</b></p>

<div id="captcha">
    <?php
          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "*****************AzBk";
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
</div>
```

then add your styles

```
#captcha-notice{
    /* styles */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, change this css  code:

```
#captcha {
    float: left;
    height: 110px;
    margin: 11px 0 20px;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 85px;
    width: 445px;
}
```

to

```
#captcha {
   float: left;
   /*height: 110px;
   margin: 11px 0 20px;*/
   padding: 2px 5px 2px 85px;
   width: 445px;
}
```